# A close formula for a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I would like to calculate "explicitly" the following integral, which is a Fourier transform: let $\alpha>0$ be a parameter, for $x\in \mathbb R$, we define
$$
I(\alpha, x)=\int_\mathbb R \cos(xt) e^{-\alpha \cosh t} dt.
$$
It is easy to see that $I(\alpha, \cdot)$ is a rapidly decreasing (even) smooth function, but I would like to have an explicit formula.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9

Comment: @user82588 --- neat find --- Mathematica is unable to evaluate it in closed form.